# How does photon addition (and subtraction) work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-optics, bosons

Photon addition and subtraction are mathematically given by the creation and annihilation operators.

$\hat{a}^{\dagger}|n\rangle=\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle$

$\hat{a}|n\rangle=\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle$

The problem is I am unable to visualize where the prefactor comes from **physically**, when I think of adding (or subtracting) a photon from an existing number state. *I am trying to make sense of it in terms of putting photons together as if they were billiard balls.*

My guess is it arises, somehow, from the indistinguishability of the bosons, but I do not have a concrete understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess this has to do with the fact that $a^{\dagger} a = N$ is the photon number operator which is such that $N|n> = n|n>$. Assuming that $a = (a^{\dagger})^{\dagger}$, and that $a^{\dagger}|n> = \alpha_n |n+1>$, you can find the prefactor using that relation.

Note that you could also define another operator $a'$ such that $a'^{\dagger}|n> = |n+1>$, but you wouldn't be able to express the photon number operator easily in terms of $a'$.

The second way to answer this is to notice that $a$ is the operator commonly associated with the "complex amplitude" field for large photon number. But because the field is roughly the square root of the intensity, which is proportional to the photon number, it makes sense that $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ roughly scale as the square root of the photon number (even though this is only approximate and the Foch states $|n>$ are *not* eigenstates of $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$.

Comment: Could you explain if the creation operator can be visualized in terms of adding another billiard ball to an existing set of billiard balls? I was thinking that as we cannot distinguish between different photons when we add a new photon to let's say 1 photon state, we can have two amplitudes corresponding to how we arrange them. So should they be in superposition like $\frac{|p_1,p_2\rangle+|p_2,p_1\rangle}{\sqrt 2}$? And how would this be same as $\sqrt{2} |2\rangle$ state?

Comment: sorry, I am not sure to understand your question. There are many subtleties when dealing with bosons and fermions, especially in the way to denote states. One way of denoting a (pure) $N$ particle state is to write as the properly (anti-)symmetrized superposition of the tensor state describing the state of each $N$ particles. The non-symmetrized state looks something like $|p_1, p_2, \dots , p_N>$ (particle $1$ in state $p_1$, particle $2$ in state $p_2$...), and the actual symmetrized state (for bosons) is $1/\sqrt{N!} \sum_{\sigma \in P} |p_{\sigma(1)}, p_{\sigma(2)}, \dots , p_{\sigma(N)}>$

Comment: With $P$ the set of all possible permutations from $(1, ..., N)$ to itself. This is called *first-quantization* and usually requires superposing a metric ton of tensor states to describe even the simplest many-body state (in fact, it requires typically $N!$ states to describe a many-body state). The symmetry/anti-symmetry properties of bosons/fermions is contained within the symmetrization of the many-body state (add $(-1)^{\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)}$ in front of each term for fermions, where $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)$ is the signature of the permutation.

Comment: The other way to write many-body states, is to use *second-quantization*. This means simply counting how many particles are in each possible state. Such a many-body state (for bosons), can be written usually like $|2, 0, 0, 5, 1, ... >$, meaning there would be $2$ bosons (among $N$) in the first state, $0$ in the second and third states, $5$ in the fourth state, $1$ in the fifth and so on... This looks very different from the big sum with $N!$ terms used in first quantization, but the two notations actually describe exactly the same many-body state, so it is really a matter of convenience.

Comment: The last thing you have to be careful about is normalization, especially for bosons. If you look at a $2$ particle state such as (in first quantization) $\frac{|p_1, p_2> + |p_2, p_1>}{\sqrt{2}}$, the $\sqrt{2}$ factor ($\sqrt{N!}$ for $N$ particles) is valid as long as $|p_1, p_2> $ and $|p_2, p_1> $ are orthogonal, which is generally true except if $p_2 = p_1$. In the latter case, the state is simply $|p_1, p_1>$.

Comment: In second quantization, there is no need for normalization factors, because they are already taken in the state. The first state (for $p_2 \neq p_1$) would look like $|1,1, 0,\dots >$ and the second state like $|2,0,0,\dots >$. The way to generate these starting from vacuum $|0, 0, \dots >$ is by successive use of the creation operators $a^{\dagger}_{p_1}$ and $a^{\dagger}_{p_2}$, so $|1, 1, 0, \dots > = a^{\dagger}_{p_1} a^{\dagger}_{p_2} |0,0,\dots >$ and $|2,0,\dots > = (a^{\dagger}_{p_1})^2/\sqrt{2} |0,0, 0,\dots>$ (the $\sqrt{2}$ comes from the fact that $a^{\dagger} |1> = \sqrt{2} |2>$).

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense now.

Comment: But in your second to last comment $\sqrt{2}$ is missing from $|p_1,p_2\rangle$ state which is incorrect (referring to this video lecture https://youtu.be/9lX2FENOe4o?t=4904 where they explicitly have $\sqrt{2}$ term in front)?

Comment: I think that's a different story, because in that case the two bosons are in different states (respectively $\chi$ and $\phi$ according to the video). The probability for the two particles to be at position $A$ and $B$ respectively is indeed $1/\sqrt{2} (\phi(A) \chi(B) + \phi(B) \chi(A))$, wether or not $A$ is equal to $B$ or not. But if the two particles are in the same state $\phi$, the wavefunction is $\phi(A) \phi(B)$ (without $\sqrt{2}$).